# Share Constants Between PHP and JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript, code-generation, dry

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Pass a PHP string to a Javascript variable (and escape newlines)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/168214/pass-a-php-string-to-a-javascript-variable-and-escape-newlines)

I have several constants in a PHP application I'm developing.  I've defined a Constants class and the defined the constants as const VAR_NAME = value; in this class.  I would like to share these constants between my JavaScript and PHP code. Is there a DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself) mechanism to share them?

```
class Constants {
    const RESOURCE_TYPE_REGSITER = 2;
    const RESOURCE_TYPE_INFO = 1;
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would use `json_encode`.  You will have to convert the class to an associative array first.

```
$constants = array("RESOURCE_TYPE_REGISTER"=>2, "RESOURCE_TYPE_INFO"=>2);
echo json_encode($constants);
```

You could also use reflection to convert the class to an associative array if you would prefer to use a class.

```
function get_class_consts($class_name)
{
    $c = new ReflectionClass($class_name);
    return ($c->getConstants());
}

class Constants {
    const RESOURCE_TYPE_REGSITER = 2;
    const RESOURCE_TYPE_INFO = 1;
}

echo json_encode(get_class_consts("Constants"));
```

Comment: You mixed JavaScript and PHP syntax. There is no JSON object in PHP. There are just json_*() functions.

Comment: Oops.  I have updated it so there is no confusion :D

Comment: This is great, however, get_class_vars seems to skip the const variables in the class.

Comment: Hey at least it's right now :)  Although I still think the simplest way is to leave it in an associative array.  And this time I actually tested it too!

Comment: Thanks, this works great.  I like using the const member variables instead of an associative array, because my IDE can then do code completion.

Answer (score 2):

Put a list of constants common to both JavaScript and PHP in "client_server_shared.js".

'var' is required in JavaScript, and is legal (though deprecated) in PHP if inside a class.  '$' to start a variable name is required in PHP, and legal in JavaScript.

```
var $shared_CONSTANT1 = 100;
var $shared_CONSTANT2 = 'hey';
```

PHP Code:

```
eval('class Client_server_shared{'                   ."\n"
.     file_get_contents( 'client_server_shared.js' ) ."\n"
.    '}'
.    '$client_server = new Client_server_shared();'
);

echo $client_server->shared_CONSTANT1;   // Proof it works in PHP.
echo $client_server->shared_CONSTANT2;
```

JavaScript Code:

```
alert( $shared_CONSTANT1 );              // Proof it works in JavaScript.
alert( $shared_CONSTANT2 );
```

Comment: I really like the simplicity of this solution, but if var is deprecated  in PHP, we should assume this solution will eventually break, right?

Answer (score -1):

The only way you can share the constants is to have the php side inform the javascript. For instance:

```
echo "<script> var CONSTANT1 =".$constant_instance->CONSTANT_NAME.";</script>";
```

Or using ajax, you could also write a small script that would return the constants as JSON/whatever.

Answer (score -2):

A bit of an ugly hack, but here it goes:

**constants.js**

```
//<?php
$const1 = 42;
$const2 = "Hello";
//?>
```

**constants.html** (use inside JavaScript)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="constants.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">document.write($const1);</script>
```

**constants.php** (use inside PHP)

```
<?php
ob_start(); // start buffering the "//"
require "constants.js";
ob_end_clean(); // discard the buffered "//"

echo $const1;
?>
```

Comment: I knew this answer would get downvotes! :)